# Assuming that the block size fork goes through, will the Bitcoin developers use the alert key to tell people to upgrade?

Tags: alert-system, block-size-increase, safemode

The [block size increase proposal](http://gavinandresen.ninja/time-to-roll-out-bigger-blocks) currently under discussion would require all clients that process transactions to upgrade.

Otherwise, pre 0.11 clients would reject these larger blocks, leading to a possible double-spend attack against these merchants after Mar 1, 2016.

Will the Bitcoin developers use the alert system to warn these nodes to upgrade?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, according to [Gavin Andresen via Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/2uuyzd/poll_should_the_maximum_block_size_be_increased/cocjhhe).

Even if they didn't to do so, Bitcoin Core already has two other mechanisms which will produce automated alerts as the hard fork approaches: [one which will take effect](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/dbca89b74b76610331d21656cd6747f5bf8375d6) before the hard fork occurs, and [one after](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/8fa9b5cc45c1826b00f305e91230c20df18885fa) (as per [BIP-50](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0050.mediawiki#safe-mode)).

Comment: Thanks for pointing those two out. I noticed that it seems to also disable some RPC commands in addition to showing a warning. https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/fc44231cb72afae2fffe0fac64e236a1d33b90e6/src/init.cpp#L243

Comment: Nice find, I didn't realize that!